Next Auth signout not working in vercel but ok in local
I am using nextAuth for signIn and signout.
My problem is that users can signIn properly (for example email:one@gmail.com pswd:0911111111), but can never signout in vercel, it will only redirect to the main page.

Here's the link of my website I deployed to vercel:
https://testforsignout.vercel.app/
However, in localhost:3000, it can signout properly, only that sometimes showing this error (but can still signout):
TypeError: Response body object should not be disturbed or locked
    at extractBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6433:17)
    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7314:48)

Because it works locally, I guess the problem is the environment variables in vercel, but I have no idea what is missing. Here's the screenshot of the environment variables:

If there is no problem in the environment variables, then I guess it's the signIn and signout function that cause the problem:
Here's the related code:
In auth/signout:
"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";

import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { publicEnv } from "@/lib/env/public";

function SignOutPage() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (session) {
      signOut({ callbackUrl: publicEnv.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL });
    }
    router.push("/");
  }, [session, router]);

  return <></>;
}

export default SignOutPage;

In LoginDialog.tsx:
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Dialog, DialogContent, DialogTrigger } from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { useState } from "react";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import { publicEnv } from "@/lib/env/public";
import AuthInput from "./AuthInput";
import { MdLogin } from "react-icons/md";
import { INDIGO } from "@/lib/constants";
import ForgotEmailDialog from "./ForgotEmailDialog";
import ForgotPasswordDialog from "./ForgotPasswordDialog";
type Props={
  sendEmail:(to:string,title:string,emailContent:string)=>void,
};
function LoginDialog({sendEmail}:Props) {
  const [open,setOpen]=useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signIn("credentials", {
      email,
      password,
      callbackUrl: `${publicEnv.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/AboutMe`,
    });
  };

  return(
    <Dialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
      <DialogTrigger asChild onClick={()=>setOpen(true)}>
        <button className="flex items-center gap-2 text-white rounded-sm hover:opacity-80 px-2 font-semibold"><MdLogin size={20} /><div>登入</div></button>
      </DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent className="w-fit">
        <div className="pt-3">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex flex-col gap-3">
            <AuthInput
              label="帳號"
              type="email"
              value={email}
              placeholder="電子郵件"
              setValue={setEmail}
            />
            <AuthInput
              label="密碼"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              placeholder="預設為手機號碼"
              setValue={setPassword}
            />
            <span className="flex text-xs self-center py-1">
              忘記&nbsp;
              <ForgotEmailDialog />
              /
              <ForgotPasswordDialog sendEmail={sendEmail}/>
            </span>
            <div className="pt-2"></div>
            <Button type="submit" className="w-full rounded-full font-semibold text-base" style={{backgroundColor: INDIGO}}>
              登入
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default LoginDialog;

In lib/auth/CredentialsProvider.ts:
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { desc, eq } from "drizzle-orm";

import { db } from "@/db";
import { experiencesTable, usersTable } from "@/db/schema";
import { authSchema } from "@/validators/auth";

export default CredentialsProvider({
  name: "credentials",
  credentials: {
    email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
    username: { label: "Userame", type: "text", optional: true },
    password: { label: "Password", type: "password"},
    mobile:{ label:"Mobile", type:"text", optional: true},
    school:{ label:"School", type:"text", optional: true}
  },
  async authorize(credentials) {
    let validatedCredentials: {
      email: string;
      username?: string;
      password: string;
      mobile?:string;
      school?:string;
    };

    try {
      validatedCredentials = authSchema.parse(credentials);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Wrong credentials. Try again.");
      return null;
    }
    const { email, password } = validatedCredentials;

    const [existedUser] = await db
      .select({
        id: usersTable.displayId,
        username: usersTable.username,
        email: usersTable.email,
        provider: usersTable.provider,
        hashedPassword: usersTable.hashedPassword,
        mobile: usersTable.mobile,
        authority: usersTable.authority,
        school: experiencesTable.school
      })
      .from(usersTable)
      .leftJoin(experiencesTable, eq(usersTable.email, experiencesTable.email))
      .orderBy(desc(experiencesTable.semester))
      .where(eq(usersTable.email, email.toLowerCase()))
      .limit(1)
      .execute();
    if(!existedUser){
      console.log("帳號不存在");
      return null;
    }
    const isValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, existedUser.hashedPassword);
    if (!isValid) {
      console.log("輸入的密碼不正確，請再次輸入");
      return null;
    }
    return {
      email: existedUser.email,
      username: existedUser.username,
      id: existedUser.id,
      mobile: existedUser.mobile,
      authority:existedUser.authority,
      school: existedUser.school??""
    };
  },
});

In lib/auth/index.ts:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

import { desc, eq } from "drizzle-orm";

import { db } from "@/db";
import { experiencesTable, usersTable } from "@/db/schema";

import CredentialsProvider from "./CredentialsProvider";

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
} = NextAuth({
  providers: [CredentialsProvider],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      const email = token.email || session?.user?.email;
      if (!email) return session;
      const [user] = await db
        .select({
          id: usersTable.displayId,
          username: usersTable.username,
          provider: usersTable.provider,
          email: usersTable.email,
          mobile: usersTable.mobile,
          authority: usersTable.authority,
          displayId: usersTable.displayId,
        })
        .from(usersTable)
        .where(eq(usersTable.email, email.toLowerCase()))
        .execute();
      const [experience]= await db.query.experiencesTable.findMany({
        columns:{
          school:true,
        },
        where:eq(experiencesTable.email,email.toLowerCase()),
        orderBy: [desc(experiencesTable.email)],
        limit: 1
      })

      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          id: user.id,
          username: user.username,
          email: user.email,
          provider: user.provider,
          mobile: user.mobile,
          authority:user.authority,
          displayId: user.displayId,
          school: experience?experience.school:""
        },
      };
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/",
  },
});

Finally, here's my github repo link:
https://github.com/Shu-Chenliu/testforsignout
I want to know what is the causing the problem and how to fix it.
